# Error loading jupyter notebook in windows10

Tags: anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on windows 10, and just recently installed Anaconda distribution. This is how the jupyter notebook is displayed every single time I run it, and so the terminal is also unavailable.
Any suggestion? How can this problem be solved? I've tried different browsers and different versions of anaconda, so what should I do now?

Thanks!

[image: Here's the image showing the details of the problem]

Comment: In Python, what does `import mimetypes; mimetypes.guess_type('foo.css')` give you?

Comment: In [1]: import mimetypes

In [2]: mimetypes.guess_type('foo.css')
Out[2]: ('application/x-css', None)

Comment: OK, that's a problem we have come across before. The correct mime type for CSS is `text/css`. Some applications on Windows add registry keys that make it the wrong thing. The only way we know of to fix it is to *carefully* edit the registry, finding the keys that say `application/x-css` and replacing it with `text/css`.

Comment: (Of course, you do anything involving the registry at your own risk, but I don't know of another way to fix it)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I don't really know how to do that. If you can guide me with the process, that'd be great!

Comment: See comments starting [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/6910#issuecomment-63536159). We're also looking at working around this in the code, but that won't be available for a while.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas! It works now!!

Comment: What do you do btw? I would like to talk to you more. Let me know if that is something you would wanna do. Thanks once again!

Comment: I am one of the people who gets to work full time on Jupyter and IPython :-). We have now merged the fix for this, by the way ([see this PR](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/1360)), so when we release ntoebook 4.3, this shouldn't be an issue again.

Comment: That's pretty cool! I'm a undergrad student, and recently got into CS. I must say, it pulls you towards itself.

Comment: It certainly does. I did my degree in plant biology before I switched into computer programming ;-)

Comment: Oh wow. That's interesting! Where from?

Comment: England - my undergrad was at Cambridge. Where are you based?

Comment: In US right now. This is actually my first year! I'm at a small liberal arts school named Earlham College.